# Get the number of empty skipped rows in pandas when parsing

Tags: python, pandas

I noticed pandas is smart when using `read_excel` / `read_csv`, it skips the empty rows so if my input has a blank row like

```
Col1, Col2
Value1, Value2
```

It just works, but is there a way to get the actual # of skipped rows? (In this case 1)

I want to tie the dataframe row numbers back to the raw input file's row numbers.

Comment: count the number of lines in the file and compare with the rows in your dataframe

Comment: In the documentation it looks like there is an argument called `skip_blank_lines: If True, skip over blank lines rather than interpreting as NaN values`. So if it's not a large file you could read it again and compare what you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `skip_blank_lines=False` and import the entire file including the empty lines. Then you can detect them, count them and filter them out:

```
def custom_read(f_name, **kwargs):
    df = pd.read_csv(f_name, skip_blank_lines=False, **kwargs)

    non_empty = df.notnull().all(axis=1)
    print('Skipped {} blank lines'.format(sum(~non_empty)))

    return df.loc[non_empty, :]
```

---

You can also use `csv.reader` to import your file row-by-row and only allow non-empty rows:

```
import csv

def custom_read2(f_name):
    with open(f_name) as f:
        cont = []
        empty_counts = 0

        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            if len(row) > 0:
                cont.append(row)
            else:
                empty_counts += 1
        print('Skipped {} blank lines'.format(empty_counts))
        return pd.DataFrame(cont)
```

As far as I can tell, at most one blank line at a time will occupy your memory. This may be useful if you happened to have large files with many blank lines, but I am pretty sure option 1 will always be the better option in practice